# How do I pass an IFormFile to my service layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC application, trying my hand at setting up a service layer. I have a pretty basic application in which I want to:

- upload an image alongside a name
- add a record to the database
- store the file on disk in the wwwroot folder with a naming convention that corresponds to the primary key of the record I just added.

Right now I've got that all that working just fine in my controller with a viewmodel. But I'd like to instead have a nice method in my service layer that does both the database add and the file system add, but I'm not finding a way to pass the file over to the service.

I figured out how to make the database add in the service layer too, but not how to get the file over there to do anything with it.

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateMentorViewModel model)
    {

        var mentor = new Mentor
        {
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            Created = DateTime.Now,
        };

        _ctx.Add(mentor);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

        int newid = mentor.Id;

        if (model.Image != null)
        {
            var uploads = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "img/profilepics");
            var fileId = newid + ".jpg"; 
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, fileId);
            model.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Mentor");

    }
```

What I'm looking for is some pointers on *how to send the file from the viewmodel in the controller to the service* or maybe more to the point - *should I do that at all?*

Comment: You have the filePath, why don't you just pass that? Or do you want to store that filePath? You could add a property to the Mentor class to store the path.

Comment: Thank you, that's doable but not quite what I'm looking for. 

Maybe the question should be around the "proper" design pattern: I'm trying to move such stuff out of the controller, so both the database work and file-writing-to-disk work are in the service layer, but maybe that's not the right way to think about it. I could easily split the two, and have the db writing in the service (passing path info along) and the disk writing in the controller. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: You can simply pass the `IFormFile` as a parameter to the service e.g. `public void MyMethod(IFormFile file) { ... }` and pass `model.Image`

Comment: that worked just fine, thank you. I'm not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Great. I've added my comment as the answer :-)

Comment: Doesn't your service then depend on Http.IFileForm? I'm not sure around the overheads but can you use a FileStream and copy to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the `IFormFile` as a parameter to the service e.g.

```
public void MyMethod(IFormFile file) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

and pass model.Image

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateMentorViewModel model)
{
    ...

    myService.MyMethod(model.Image);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Your service layer would depend on the asp implementation

Comment: I see no problem with this, absolutely nothing wrong with depending on asp's implementation. That's like saying "cant depend on Microsoft's `string` implementation".

Comment: @mxmissile depends. The service layer cannot be reused by a worker console app for example. More than that, imagine having to migrate from one framework to another (and who went from .NET Framework to .NET Core will def agree with Sergio Escudero).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't depend on ASP.NET in your service layer. Pass on `Stream` instead:

```
var result = await myService.ProcessFileAsync(formFile.OpenReadStream());
```